# When I try to run this code, it is giving the NameError, saying : name 'x' is not defined, It is happening only when I implicitly try to run all cases

Tags: python, dictionary

When I try to run this code, it is giving the NameError, saying: name 'x' is not defined, It is happening only when I implicitly try to run all cases

```
    dict={}
    for queryname in dict.keys():
        if queryname in dict.keys()
        x=dict.get(queryname)
    formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(sum(x)/3)
    print(formatted_float)
```

Comment: As written, this throws a SyntaxError. Your if statement is missing a colon and the following three lines should be indented within the if. Also, don't name a variable `dict`, as this is a built-in function

Comment: Also, please give enough code to reproduce the problem. E.g. at least two "cases". Refer [mcve]

Comment: Given an empty dict, `for queryname in dict.keys():` will execute exactly zero times.  Nothing in the body of that loop will happen - including the only assignment to `x`.

Comment: It is actually a typo error!, I had put a semicolon while running the code

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is empty, then the for loop will never run, because it has nothing to iterate on. The body of the loop will never be executed, and that includes the assignment of `x`. You can either add some keys to `d`, or assign `x` to some value before the loop.

```py
# Adding keys
d = {0:1, 2:3} #Don't use dict as a variable name, that collides with the python keyword.
for queryname in d.keys():
        if queryname in d.keys()
        x = d.get(queryname)
    formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(sum(x)/3)
    print(formatted_float)
```

```py
#Assigning a value to x
d = {}
x=0
for queryname in d.keys():
        if queryname in d.keys()
        x = d.get(queryname)
    formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(sum(x)/3)
    print(formatted_float)
```

Comment: Just like mentioned in a comment on the question, do not use `dict` as a variable name as that's a python built-in function name.